# Evaluate $\int_{x=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}(1-e^{-x})\right)^{M-1}e^{-x}(1+sx)^{-N}dx,$

Tags: calculus, analysis, asymptotics, improper-integrals

I am trying to evaluate
$$\int_{x=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}(1-e^{-x})\right)^{M-1}e^{-x}(1+sx)^{-N}dx,$$
where $s>0$, $M$ and $N$ are positive integers.

But seem that the above integral does not not have a closed form expression.

Then I step back and want only an expression for very large $s$, i.e. as $s \rightarrow \infty $, but seems that dominate Dominated convergence theorem theorem also does not work for it.

Can anyone tell me how can I deal with this integral?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *the above integral does not have a closed form expression*

Not for a general *M*, no. Not unless you're willing to throw [hypergeometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) into the mix. But it does for each particular value of *M*.

> *Can anyone tell me how I can deal with this integral ?*

Yes. The whole idea is to write $I(a)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\bigg(\frac{1-e^{-x}}{\sqrt x}\bigg)^m\frac{e^{-x}}{a+sx}~dx,~$ and then to notice that

your integral is nothing else than a multiple of $I^{(n)}(1)$, where $m=M-1$, and $n=N-1$. For

$m=0$ we have $~I(a)=\dfrac{\exp\bigg(\dfrac as\bigg)~\Gamma\bigg(0,~\dfrac as\bigg)}s~,$ and for $m=1$ we get $~I(a)=\pi~\dfrac{\exp\bigg(\dfrac as\bigg)}{\sqrt{as}}\cdot$

$\cdot\bigg[\text{erfc}\bigg(\sqrt{\dfrac as}\bigg)-\exp\bigg(\dfrac as\bigg)~\text{erfc}\bigg(\sqrt{2~\dfrac as}\bigg)\bigg],~$ etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you mean  $I^{n}(a)=\left(\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\bigg(\frac{1-e^{-x}}{\sqrt x}\bigg)^m\frac{e^{-x}}{a+sx}~dx\right)^n~$?

Comment: Or do you mean the derivative respect to $s$?

Comment: @user2008790: The n-th derivative with respect to *a*. If I would take it with regard to *s*, I would get an extra $x^n$ in the integrand.